# How to dynamically change the content of a facet in a custom component?

Tags: jsf, richfaces

Let's consider that I want to extend an existing JSF component, such as the `<rich:datatable/>`. My main requirement is to dynamically modify the content of a `<f:facet>`, to change its content.

What is the best way to achieve that? Or *where* is the best place in the code to achieve that?

In my `faces-config.xml`, I have the following declaration:

```
<faces-config>
    ...
    <component>
        <component-type>my.component.dataTable</component-type>
        <component-class>my.project.component.table.MyHtmlDataTable</component-class>
    </component>
    ...
    <render-kit>
        <render-kit-id>HTML_BASIC</render-kit-id>
        <renderer>
            <component-family>org.richfaces.DataTable</component-family>
            <renderer-type>my.renderkit.dataTable</renderer-type>
            <renderer-class>my.project.component.table.MyDataTableRenderer</renderer-class>
        </renderer>
        ...
```

Also, my `my-project.taglib.xml` file (as I use Facelets) looks like:

```
<facelet-taglib>
    <namespace>http://my.project/jsf</namespace>
    <tag>
        <tag-name>dataTable</tag-name>
        <component>
            <component-type>my.component.dataTable</component-type>
            <renderer-type>my.renderkit.dataTable</renderer-type>
        </component>
    </tag>
```

So as you can see, I have two classes in my project for my custom datatable: `MyHtmlDataTable` and `MyDataTableRenderer`.
One of my idea is to modify the content of the `<f:facet>` directly in the `doEncodeBegin()` method of my renderer. This is working (in fact [almost working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728387/actions-are-not-working-when-modifying-the-facet-of-a-custom-datatable)), but I don't really think that's the better place to achieve my modification.

What do you think?

*Technical information: JSF 1.2, Facelets, Richfaces 3.3.2, Java 1.6*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can call `getFacet(facetName)` and make the modifications on the returned component.

You can override `getFacets()` (and/or `getFacet(..)`), call the `super` method and make the modifications on the returned value, and then return it.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I do, but my question is to know where I have to do that? Because for the moment, I do the modification on the renderer class, during the RENDER_VIEW phase, but I am not fully satisfied with this solution...